# When extending an object; why not use "this" instead of "super" when changing object members

Tags: apache-flex, oop, actionscript

This question is posed from an ActionScript context but could be from a Java one equally.

The code I am using as a sample comes from [adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html). In the code extract below the **NoteCard** class has an **enabled** and a **disabled** state which it inherits from the **SkinnableComponent** class.  My question is; why in the enabled setter do we call super.enabled = value; and not this.enabled = value;. We have created our NoteCard object instance from the constructor and should we not then be able to set the value of the **enabled** member using the "this" keyword. If you do swap **super** for  **this** no errors are shown by the compiler but the code fails to work.

```
    package
    {

     import spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableComponent;

      public class NoteCard extends SkinnableComponent
      {
       public function NoteCard()
       {
        super();
       }


      override public function set enabled(value:Boolean) : void
      {
       if (enabled != value)
       invalidateSkinState();

      super.enabled = value;
      }

      override protected function getCurrentSkinState() : String
      {
       if (!enabled)
       return "disabled";

      return "normal"
      }

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If we'll use:

```
  override public function set enabled(value:Boolean) : void
  {
   if (enabled != value)
   invalidateSkinState();

  enabled = value;
  }
```

We'll run into infinite loop. This line:

```
enabled = value;
```

will call the same setter again and again.

Comment: unrelated, but i use this same type of example in interview tests with devs

Answer (score 0):

In this special case you override a setter for a class. You can implement your own additional code to handle the newly set value, but the code from your superclass should also be called, because you may not know, what the base class setter will do (may be set a private variable with a value). You have to call `super.setterName = value` to assure this. If you would call with `this` you would call your implemented setter in an infinite loop. You may omit the `super` call, if you are sure, this isn't necessary.

Comment: I get it now? Thanks. Its straight forward now that my eyes have been opened but really a fundamental point.